# django not rendering template in html but as ordinariny textfile on browser

Tags: django

all my codes are working correctly but showing as text on browser. they are not rendering as an html page

here is what my views is like

```
    @login_required
def product_list(request, template_name='product/product_list.html'):
    ppix = Profilepix.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    product = Product.objects.filter(username=request.user).order_by('-postdate')
    data = {}
    data['object_list'] = product
    return render(request, template_name, data, {'Profilepix': ppix})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the `Profilepix` as a *header* in the HTTP response. If you want to pass both items to the [**`render(…)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render), then you should pass a dictionary with two entries, so:

```
@login_required
def product_list(request, template_name='product/product_list.html'):
    ppix = Profilepix.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    product = Product.objects.filter(username=request.user).order_by('-postdate')
    data = {
        'object_list': product,
        'Profilepix': ppix
    }
    return render(request, template_name, data) # no fourth item
```

Comment: @user16728502: did you remove the `{'Profilepix': ppix}` in the `render(...)` call?

Comment: yes, i did. it is working on the template. i can see the data from the database but it shows as text on browser not rendering as html

Comment: i also noticed it is working on my local server. but does not work on remote server.

Comment: @user16728502: then likely the server did not restart. The fourth parameter is the `content_type`, so by using `{'Profilepix': ppix}` it used an *unknown* content type, hence it is rendered as text, but by removing that, it works again with the `text/html`, which is the one to render it as a HTML file.

Comment: ok thanks so much. i will get back to you